# Using Matlab to send digital signal from National Instruments device

Tags: matlab

I currently have a circuit set up with an NI USB-6501 connected to a mux and was wondering how to use MATLAB to send a digital signal from the NI device to the mux.

Comment: No practical experience here as I have only used Matlab for mathematical modelling but there is information on using NI devices with Matlab [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/daq/examples/acquire-data-using-ni-devices.html).

Comment: I've looked at that and didn't find it very useful but I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by Warren is for analogue. Click [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/adddigitalchannel.html) for digital.

From what I understand you are trying to get Matlab to send a digital signal to the NI and then the NI sends a signal to the MUX. If that is what you are trying to do then you need have code in your NI to take the data received from Matlab and transmit it to the MUX.

You need to distinguish are you only trying to communicate with the NI or are you trying to programme the firmware of the NI using Matlab as well?

If you are only trying to communicate with it then that link is all you need (provided you have already coded the NI to handle the data)